# Laravel Cashier Return Subscription Information

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.3, laravel-cashier

I am having a major headache whilst implementing Laravel Cashier, I have successfully created a subscription, charged the card, recieved the token and store all said info in the subscriptions table.

I am doing this using the following code, for some reason the standard methods are not working:

```
public function createSubscription(Request $request) {

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
      Auth::user('id')->newSubscription('monthly', 'basic')->trialDays(30)->create($request->stripeToken);
      Session::flash('message', 'Your subscription has been updated, thank you.');
            return view('pages.packages')->with('user', Auth::user());
}
```

As much as this differs from the standard code we are told to use, it works!
Moving on, so when the data gets in the table, I should be able to call the next cashier to check if the user is subscribed;

```
$user->subscribed();
```

Ofcourse, if we go by way I had to structure the code before that, we end up with something like this;

```
Auth::user('id')->subscribed();
```

This is not working, it is not erroring out, it is just returning false every time, so to avoid views and all that, I did this;

```
dd(Auth::user('id')->subscribed());
```

And all that shows is false, no matter the user or package they are on!

I feel like there is something maybe missing from my User.php which is where we have attached the Cashier to be part of the User model! Like so;

```
namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;



class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Billable;
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'trial_ends_at', 'subscription_ends_at',
];
}
```

Now I could be making a really obvious mistake here, but this application is engulfing my existence here so any help would much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: "I am doing this using the following code, for some reason the standard methods are not working..." Why don't you start there? What standard methods? Why aren't they working? Such a thing speaks to larger issues in your application that should be resolved.

Comment: Well quite frankly the standard method would consist of me converting, the Auth part into a variable of $user....
So there is only a small difference on that part.
I have been scouring the web for hours trying to figure just that out.\
Is there anything that you can suggest?
Thanks

Comment: The current user can be accessed via `$request->user()`, or you can use contracts and dependency injection to do `public function createSubscription(Request $request, \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory $user)` to automatically make `$user` available to your function.

Comment: After you've reviewed dependency injection and contracts, try using `subscribed('plan-name')` with whatever your plan is called.

Comment: Ok so I have made the modifications you suggested, which work, thank you... So now I am using the standard call of    $user->subscribed('basic');

Comment: It is still showing false on the return, this is very frustrating! The user is definitely on the correct plan etc.

Comment: I don't understand how the information is getting put in the databse and from within the same controller, using the correct code it still shows false, Maybe my User.php is wrong or something, I posted it above, I can't figure it! Thanks v much for your help btw

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `subscribed('monthly')`, not `subscribed('basic')`, based on your new subscription code.

Comment: Holy whatsit, you did it! That is fantastic, it really isn't clear in the docs, I was under the impression the plan name would be the id of my stripe plan, which is basic! Thank you very much man. Now on to trying to make posts only show published for user whos are subscribed... Any ideas on that would be a bonus :)

Answer (score 2):

With many thanks to @ceejayoz the answer to this little issue is not to call the actual plan id that is saved to stripe, it is to call the ('monthly') instead!

```
$user->subscribed('monthly');
```

Comment: What kind of a dumb setup is this??? To pass a subscription name instead of id??? God Lord I've spent 3 hours trying to figure out why everything related to subscriptions is null on my models. I swear I accidentally read your answer, you've saved me a day of work probably.